# Are there long term support distros that offer Gnome 3 as their primary desktop environment?

Tags: linux, gnome, linux-distributions

Are there long term support distros that offer Gnome 3 as their primary desktop environment? I know ubuntu offers native Gnome3, for example, but since the focus of Ubuntu is on Unity, I'd be afraid about the packaging quality and the level of support.

So what are good, stable distros that offer Gnome3 as their primary desktop environment?

Answer (score -2):

openSuse uses Gnome 2.x (I forgot which one specifically) by default, but there is an update in the repositories that allow you to replace everything with Gnome3 and Gnome3-compatible components. But if you want extremely bleeding edge, use Arch Linux. Arch Linux's nightly builds are literally bleeding edge (some packages are known to break something on rare occasions, but if you know what you need and where to fix it everything is fixable!). They package applications as they roll out. In fact

Comment: Thanks for answering, but... did you read my question?

Comment: Ahh, then scratch Arch Linux. openSuse is a good alternative. I sometimes ramble on, sorry about that. :)

Comment: No problem then :) OpenSuse isn't bad, but the release cycle is a tad short to qualify for a long term support distro. Also, I'm looking for distros that offer Gnome3 as their primary choice of desktop. I'm starting to think that Fedora is the only choice at the moment.

Comment: RHEL/CentOS ( fedora downstreams and supported for 10years each) are an option.